# QGIS flow direction mesh to shape format

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mesh

I have calculated flow direction meshes in QGIS using PCRaster tool and Crayfish plugins.
The result (white lines) I get is the following (see screenshot):
[image]

Is it somehow possible to extract this (white) lines and convert them to shapefile format (.SHP)?

Comment: Are the lines in raster format?

Comment: The file that contains data to show these lines is in .grb (or GRIB) format.